Is there a way to track app usage with Unity?
I'm trying to make an app with Unity designed to stop using the phone for periods of time, how would I track what apps are open and when they open? Is there any way to do so in Android? Also, I would need it to work even when the app is in the background or when the phone isn't being used. Is there any way to do so?
I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start.

almost certainly doable in some form, however, unity sounds like the last place to be doing it. You want more of a silent service to constantly run gently in background, not flashy graphics.
